# How can I check for date range exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select

As you may have noticed from title, my question is quite difficult to express, but there is problem:

I have MySQL table with some data:

[image]

In registration form I have to specify reservation start and end times. How can I check, whether there is already registered reservation for specified time or not. For example I should not be able to put new reservation which starts at 13:20 and ends at 15:00 etc.

Comment: You can always use BETWEEN key word.
For eg: SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE DATE BETWEEN <X> AND <Y>

Comment: Why everyday there are at least 3-4 people who ask the same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either the start or the end of the new reservation you want to create is inside a current range, the reservation should be blocked. Using `:reservationStart` and `:reservationEnd` as these dates, you could query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   reservations
WHERE  :reservationStart BETWEEN reservation_from AND reservation_to OR
       :reservationEnd BETWEEN reservation_from AND reservation_to OR
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `:reservationStart < reservation_to AND :reservationEnd > reservation_from`

Comment: @Strawberry that condition will catch only new reservations that contain existing reservations, and will miss new reservations that **intersect** with existing ones.

Comment: Mureinik, you're mistaken. Time is linear. Events cannot end before they begin. Draw a diagram if it helps.

Comment: @Strawberry no, I'm not. Consider a new reservation that starts before all the pre-existing reservation but end before all pre-existing reservations too. Such a reservation should be dis-allowed, as some of its days are already booked. Your query misses this use case.

Comment: My code accounts for that case. reservationStart < reservation_to but reservationEnd !> reservation_from

Comment: @Strawberry indeed, I misread. However, it misses a new reservation that's contained in an existing one.

Comment: Would it help if I drew a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Use anti semi join, below query return rooms which are available for booking in given check in and out range. It's in Rails.

Relation

Booking belongs to Room

Room has many Booking

Query

check_in_at = '2016-12-28'

check_out_at = '2016-12-29'

Room.where.not("EXISTS (SELECT bookings.* FROM bookings where rooms.id = bookings.room_id AND bookings.check_in_at BETWEEN ? AND ? AND bookings.check_out_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)", check_in_at, check_out_at, check_in_at, check_out_at)